# Local UIImage not show in open graph story Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiimage, facebook-opengraph

I'm try to publish a local photo in a Facebook open graph story, but the image is not appears.

[image]

This code is the same of the documentation page of Facebook developers. [facebook_developers open graph ios](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios#sharedialog)

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coffee-and-sunrise.jpg"];
// Optionally set user generated to YES only if this image was created by the user
// You must get approval for this capability in your app's Open Graph configuration
// photo.userGenerated = YES;

// Create an object
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                                @"og:type": @"books.book",
                                @"og:title": @"A Game of Thrones",
                                @"og:description": @"In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.",
                                @"books:isbn": @"0-553-57340-3",
                            };

FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

// Create an action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"books.reads";
[action setObject:object forKey:@"books:book"];

// Add the photo to the action. Actions
// can take an array of images.
[action setArray:@[photo] forKey:@"image"];

// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"books:book";

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                  withContent:content
                  delegate:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is aware this is broken on iOS and has marked it as "won't fix".  Incredibly agitating, please do voice your concern on the bug report they've acknowledged [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/732978923469934/).